# Updating SQL Server CE database bound to DataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm new to SQL and I'm a little unsure about the best way to use the database in the program I'm writing.

My program saves "notes" to an SQL Server CE database. A note row consists of an auto-incrementing `ID (int)`, a `title (string)` and the text of the note, which is stored in the database as `ntext`.

I have a `SqlCeDataAdapter` loading the ID and title rows into a `DataTable` which is bound to a `DataGrid`, so the user can see the list of notes and select one. I don't load the text row because I assume it could be large and so it doesn't need to be in memory all the time.

```
string ConnectionString = "DataSource = " + @"..\\..\\Notes.sdf";
DatabaseConnection = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
DatabaseConnection.Open();

SqlCeCommand SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT ID, title FROM notes_id", DatabaseConnection);
DatabaseAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(SelectCommand);

NotesDataTable = new DataTable();
DatabaseAdapter.Fill(NotesDataTable);

MainWindowDataView = NotesDataTable.DefaultView;
dataGridNotes.DataContext = MainWindowDataView;
```

The problem is when I add a new note. Should I be updating the `DataTable` and using that to update the SQL database? Or should I be directly updating the SQL database and use that to reload the `DataTable` to update it?

The problem with updating the `DataTable` is that I don't have a column there for the text of the note. And if I insert a new row, I'm not sure how to refer to that new row to add the text cell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should insert the new row into the database and then reload your DataTable (and your view of the data) with a fresh query from the db. Seems too simple though so you may need to elaborate the problem a bit.